# What is wrong with this PHP PDO routine?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm starting out with PDO and trying to replace this code, which works:

```
$dbh->query("INSERT INTO sugestao (id, fbid, username, latitude, longitude, endereco, categoria, titulo, descricao, foto)
                        VALUES (null, 
                            '".$fbid."', 
                            '".$username."', 
                            '".$lat."', 
                            '".$lon."', 
                            '".$endereco."',
                            '".$categoria."', 
                            '".$titulo."',
                            '".$descricao."',
                            '".$foto."')");
```

With this one, that seems safer and better maintainable, and that should also allow me to safely get the last ID inserted:

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();

    $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO sugestao (id, fbid, username, latitude, longitude, endereco, categoria, titulo, descricao, foto)
                        VALUES (null, :fbid, :username, :lat, :lon, :endereco, :categoria, :titulo, :descricao, :foto)");
    $dbh->bindParam(":fbid", $fbid);
    $dbh->bindParam(":username", $username);
    $dbh->bindParam(":lat", $lat);
    $dbh->bindParam(":lon", $lon);
    $dbh->bindParam(":endereco", $endereco);
    $dbh->bindParam(":categoria", $categoria);
    $dbh->bindParam(":titulo", $titulo);
    $dbh->bindParam(":descricao", $descricao);
    $dbh->bindParam(":foto", $foto);
    $dbh->execute();
    $lastid = $dbh->lastInsertId();
    $dbh->commit();
```

This second one, gives me a 500 Server Error. Any clues?

Comment: What is the error message from your apache / php error log?

Comment: `$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO sugestao (id, fbid, username, latitude, longitude, endereco, categoria, titulo, descricao, foto)
                        VALUES ('null', ':fbid', ':username', ':lat', ':lon', ':endereco', ':categoria', ':titulo', ':descricao', ':foto')");`

Try that.

Comment: The point of PDO is to use placeholders. In your first example you're side-stepping any benefits of PDO and creating **enormous** bugs. @grunk has the answer.

Comment: @tadman That's precisely why i wanted to change. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bindParam` and `execute` are function from [PDOStatement](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/class.pdostatement.php) and not from PDO :

```
$statement = $dbh->prepare(...);
$statement->bindParam();
$statement->execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

`$dbh->bindParam()` is not defined.

```php
// Create the statement
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO sugestao (id, fbid, username, latitude, longitude, endereco, categoria, titulo, descricao, foto)
                       VALUES (null, :fbid, :username, :lat, :lon, :endereco, :categoria, :titulo, :descricao, :foto)");

// Bind parameters
$stmt->bindParam(":fbid", $fbid);
// ...
$stmt->bindParam(":foto", $foto);

// Execute the statement
try {
    $dbh->beginTransaction();
    $stmt->execute();
    $dbh->commit();
} catch (PDOExecption $e) {
    $dbh->rollback();
    // Do whatever you want
}

// Read last ID on the statement
$lastId = $stmt->lastInsertId();
```